# Quick Replace in Visual Studio 2010 fails to use Tagged Expression n

Tags: visual-studio-2010, regex

I'm trying to do some basic regex Quick Replace operations in Visual Studio 2010, but when I use regex grouping I don't get Tagged Expressions (ie. `\1 \2` etc.) returning their values, instead they are blank.

For example:

**Text**

```
int a = int.Parse("10");
int b = int.Parse("20");
int c = int.Parse("30");
```

**Search Pattern (regex enabled)**

```
int\.Parse\("([0-9]*)"\);
```

**Replace**

```
\1;
```

**Replaced Text**

```
int a = ;
int b = ;
int c = ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(, ) don't create a tag in Visual Studio, its regular expressions use {,} for its tagging.  Use this are you search pattern:

```
int\.Parse\("{[0-9]*}"\);
```